# SQL - Ignoring / Removing Duplicates based on Two Columns

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Suppose I have a single table `actions` like so:

```
+----+------------+--------+-------+
| id |    rdate   | clicks | epoch |
+----+------------+--------+-------+
|  1 | 2020-01-01 |    100 |  1200 |
|  1 | 2020-01-01 |     95 |  1100 |
|  1 | 2020-10-12 |     42 |  1000 |
|  1 | 2020-10-12 |     66 |   900 |
+----+------------+--------+-------+
```

I am trying to write a query that gives me the number of clicks based on the `MAX(epoch)` for records with identical values in the `id` and `rdate` columns - the end result should be: (note, I do not need the `epoch` column in the result)

```
+----+------------+--------+
| id |    date    | clicks |
+----+------------+--------+
|  1 | 2020-01-01 |    100 |
|  1 | 2020-10-12 |     42 |
+----+------------+--------+
```

I have tried the following query but the duplicates are still present in the result. The `group by` query does remove duplicates when run by itself, but the inner join to get the `clicks` does not work as intended.

```sql
SELECT
    id,
    rdate,
    clicks
FROM actions a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        id,
        rdate, 
        MAX(epoch)
    from actions  
    group by 
        id,
        rdate
) b 
on a.id = b.id
and a.rdate = b.rdate;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id, rdate ORDER BY epoch DESC) rn
    FROM actions
)

SELECT id, rdate, clicks, epoch
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

If you want to stick with your current join approach, then you need to fix the logic such that the join to the subquery also restricts the number of clicks:

```sql
SELECT a1.*
FROM actions a1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT id, rdate, MAX(epoch) AS max_epoch
    FROM actions
    GROUP BY id, rdate
) a2
    ON a2.id = a1.id AND a2.rdate = a1.rdate AND a2.max_epoch = a1.epoch;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use **[QUALIFY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/qualify.html)** and windowed function:

```
SELECT *
FROM actions
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id, rdate ORDER BY epoch DESC) = 1
```

Comment: @Daniel . . . This is the best solution and should be the accepted answer.